# How to change visibility of FooterRow and Columns on Button Click - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visibility

I have a GridView with about 16 columns, for aesthetic reasons I only want to display certain columns, however if a user wants  to insert a row (which uses the footer row) I would need to make the rest of columns visible.

On Page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Add_Button.Text != "Cancel")
    {
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[16].Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

And upon button click:

```
protected void Add_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.FooterRow.Visible == false)
    {
        GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[9].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = true;
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
        Add_Button.Text = "Cancel";
        Panel2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {                    
        Add_Button.Text = "Add New Record"; 
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Client Side the Footer Row's Visibility is set to true and the extra columns' visibility is set to false. I've been playing with setting the Footer Row's visibility to false, setting the columns visibility to true and so on but nothing seems to be giving me the results I want.

Currently, as it is on first button click the extra rows and footer row is made visible, and on second click, which is supposed to make them invisible again, it only makes the footer row invisible but not the columns. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

Since you don't have `if (!this.IsPostBack)` block in your `Page_Load` method, then all of the code in `Page_Load` method will be executed before `Add_Button_Click` method is executed when you click `Add_Button`.

On the second click, here's what happens in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Add_Button.Text != "Cancel")
    {
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[16].Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // this block is executed because Add_Button.Text is "Cancel",
        // which was the result of the first click
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

and here's what happens in `Add_Button_Click`:

```
protected void Add_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.FooterRow.Visible == false)
    {
        GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[9].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = true;
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
        Add_Button.Text = "Cancel";
        Panel2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // this block is executed because GridView1.FooterRow.Visible is true,
        // which was the result of Page_Load execution on the second click
        Add_Button.Text = "Add New Record"; 
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

That's why the columns aren't made visible on the second click.

### The Solution

I assume what you currently have in `Page_Load` method is supposed to be executed on the first load of the page, so you need to add `if (!this.IsPostBack)` block as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Add_Button.Text != "Cancel")
        {
            GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[16].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and change `Add_Button_Click` method as below:

```
protected void Add_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.FooterRow.Visible == false)
    {
        GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[9].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = true;
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
        Add_Button.Text = "Cancel";
        Panel2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[9].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
        Add_Button.Text = "Add New Record"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: That got rid of the extra columns but upon clicking the button the second time (which is now the cancel button) the footer row remains. I want to get rid of that as well.

Comment: Have you tried to debug and put a break point in `Add_Button_Click` method? When you click the button for the second time, the `else` block in `Add_Button_Click` method will be executed, so the footer row shouldn't be visible because of this syntax: `GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;` in the `else` block.

Comment: Yea I did and realized that after the event it jumps over to the client side and it looks like it re-does the gridview and because by default the footer row is visible, it stays that way. If it was set to false in the client side it does the same thing except stays invisible.

Comment: What do you mean `If it was set to false in the client side`? What client side? Do you have some client side / javascript code that sets the visibility of the footer row?